# Android SDK does not appear in intellij

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I want to add android SDK that i have been installed, but in the Intellij there is not android SKD

[image: Intellij]

and this is where my android-sdk has been installed

[image: android-sdk-path]

so what should i do ?
i have tried everywhere in Intellij but there is not android-sdk

also when i wanna create a new android project, there is not android !!!

[image]

Comment: Looks like you change JDK instead of sdk. Lookc acurate to your window and your find SDKs item. In this menu choose your location

Comment: i have already installed JDK and now i wanna install SDK and i couldnt find it

Comment: may be better install AndroidStodio for this purpose? I dont remember exactly, but my lust install of Iday propose me add Android module. By the way, in my first comment i mean your first screen. Look at first column, find platform settings and check SDKs subtitle

Comment: @Moolerian if you use Intellij IDEA you must be sure you have installed Android Support plugin. Check File -> Settings -> Plugins.

Comment: As @once2go already said, it may be better to use Android Studio IDE, which based on Intellij IDEA and it already includes everything you need for Android development (no need to install a plugin)

Answer (score 2):

Vadik's answer in the comment above helped me.

After a software update on my mac, somehow intellij lost track of my android support plugin. I had my android project working fine and then it could not recognize the SDK and when I deleted and tried to re-add it, there was no option to add and android sdk and you described in your question above. I went to (on mac) Intellij IDEA menu > Preferences > Plugins and Android Support plugin was greyed out and unchecked. I checked off the Android Support plugin, clicked Apply and had to restart Intellij. Then I was able to add Android SDK normally in Project Structure menu.